# unable to see excel formula suggestions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am not able to see any excel formula suggestions.

When I press `=` and type any word in any excel cell then excel should automatically display some formula suggestions.

This is not working for me.

How can I see those formula suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### How can I see those formula suggestions?

You need to **select** (enable) Formula AutoComplete:

> **Turn Formula AutoComplete on or off**
>
> - Click the Microsoft Office Button [image: Office button image], click Excel Options, and then click the Formulas category.
> - Under Working with formulas, **select** or clear Formula AutoComplete.

Source [Use Formula AutoComplete](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Formula-AutoComplete-6d13daa5-e003-4431-abab-9edef51fae6b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)